# jquery POST data append not happening

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append some string before data output. Please help me figure out in how to do it. I have tried both HTML and append function, but I am not getting desired output.

Like if `data = abc`, it should show `data = xyzabc` and append `xyz` automatically to JSON data

```
data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "a.php",
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    $(".the-return").html(
      data
    );
```

Comment: try `$(".the-return").html(
                "xyz" + data
            );`

Comment: yes its working fine with above code thanks

Comment: well if my answer is right please mark it as accepted ...see how here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the string "xyz" to the output data as "xyz" +data

try

```
$(".the-return").html( "xyz" + data );
```